# Sending a Object of javascript to a php page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
start.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  mediaRecorder.start(10000);
  console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
});
stop.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
  mediaRecorder.stop();
  mediaStreamObj.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
  console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
});
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
    //vidSave.src=null; 
    chunks = ev.data;
    b++;
    //let blob= new Blob(chunks,{type : 'video/mp4'});

    //let videoURL= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
    var formData = new FormData();
    var replacer = function(k, v) {
      if (v === undefined) {
        return null;
      }
      return v;
    };
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(chunks, replacer);
    //var file= new File([chunks],b+"v");
    console.log(stringData);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "upload-video.php",
      data: {
        data: stringData
      }
    });
```

`stringData` is becoming an empty JSON any other way to send it to php page?

Comment: In the future please format your code so that other people can read it. What is `chunks`? What is `mediaRecorder`? If `stringData` is empty, then because `chunks` doesn't have any enumerable properties to serialize. Without knowing what the value of `chunks` is we cannot propose a solution.

Comment: File
​{
lastModified: 1552499210447
​
name: ""
​
size: 1035267
​
type: "video/webm"
​
webkitRelativePath: ""
​
<prototype>: FilePrototype { name: Getter, lastModified: Getter, webkitRelativePath: Getter, … } this is how chunks looks when displayed through console.

Comment: basically chunk contains a 10sec video recorded through webcam

Comment: So it's a file object. What result do you expect after serializing it to JSON?

Comment: actually the main goal is to share this file object to another php page, i don't know the correct way i used serializing.

Comment: So the best way to share this object would be?

Comment: If you want to upload a file, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files

Comment: Can't i share the file object?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "share". Sending a file to the server, which I assume is what you mean with "send it to PHP page", is typically called "uploading". But you can call it whatever you want, it doesn't change what it actually does.

Comment: can't i take this file object to server and use it?

Comment: I am thinking of converting this file object to video on server and perform required analysis will this happen?

Comment: *"can't i take this file object to server and use it?"* Yes you can. That's what I mean with "if you want to upload the file". The link tells you how to do it. There are also multiple questions about how to do this with jQuery, but it's pretty much the same as in the link: Create a `FormData` object with the file and pass that to jQuery.

Comment: As you said using formData, i already tried this i need your help in sharing this file object and on making file object work at server. Any procedure that could work? Thanks in advance

Comment: `const data = new FormData(); data.add('file', chunks); $.ajax({data: data, ...})` should just work. Not much else to add to that. If you have problems accessing uploaded files on the server side, that's a different issue. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: It's throwing an error if we use add- it is saying add is not a function

Comment: Sorry, looks like the method is `append`. Always read documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: if we use add- it is saying add is not a function  so i changed it to append then its saying following error- TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: `var data = new FormData(); data.append('foo', 'bar');` works just fine for me in the browser console. If you get an error then your either doing something differently or something about your environment is different. Impossible to say what the issue without knowing anything about it.

Comment: Is bar a file object?  I feel like FormData is not working for object or the way we did

Comment: The value can be a string or a Blob, which includes File. If you believe the value is the issue, try it with a string first. If it works then the issue is indeed the value and you need to figure out how to convert it to a Blob.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks but it's not working value is the whole thing.